# How to push python artifacts to GCP artifact registry, from a workload identity container in GKE

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cicd, google-artifact-registry, workload-identity

I am trying to implement a simple CD pipeline for a python library, my tech-stack looks like this:

- **Jenkins** server using a **GKE cluster** as build agent
- **GCP Artifact Registry** python repo to host my libraries

Then, the integration I have so far looks as follow:

1. **GCP SA** and a **K8s SA** configured as **Workload Identity**
2. Pod in GKE with workload Identity:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: agent
spec:

  serviceAccountName: <k8s-sa>
  nodeSelector:
    iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"

  containers:
  - image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
    name: gcloud-sdk-alpine
    command: ["sleep","infinity"]
```

Finally my pipeline stage to push the python library is based on [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication) with some tweaks that make sense in the scope of the container:

```bash
# install pip in the gcloud-sdk-alpine container
apk add py-pip

# install python packages
pip install keyring \
    keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth \
    twine

# creates the .pypirc 
printf "[distutils]\nindex-servers = \n    ${env.REPO_NAME}\n\n[${env.REPO_NAME}]\nrepository: https://${env.REGION}-python.pkg.dev/${env.PROJECT_ID}/${env.REPO_NAME}/\n" > ~/.pypirc

# using sample app to do a POC artifact upload
pip download sampleproject

# using twine to upload the artifact
# sampleproject-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl is one of the files downloaded by pip download sampleproject
twine upload --repository-url https://${env.REGION}-pypi.pkg.dev/${env.PROJECT_ID}/${env.REPO_NAME} sampleproject-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

After all this configuration, the result is a weird **413 Request Entity Too Large Error**. I know this error is not accurate, since I am able to push the exact same file from my local machine. I am not sure whether this misleading error has been put there on purpose or it is a bug from GCP Artifact Registry (Python repo).

I ssh'ed into the container to debug the issue, and the only odd finding was the output of the keyring validation command `keyring --list-backends` shown in the documentation, which was returning me a different priority for the backends.

Answer (score 1):

After checking a couple of blogs
https://hilliao.medium.com/google-recommended-security-iam-practice-on-gke-a58ddfb605a3 and https://lukwam.medium.com/python-packages-in-artifact-registry-d2f63643d2b7

I figured out the right set of commands to make this push go trough.

```bash
# install pip in the gcloud-sdk-alpine container
apk add py-pip

# install python packages
pip install twine keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth wheel

# using sample app to do a POC artifact upload
pip download sampleproject

# using twine to upload the artifact
# sampleproject-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl is one of the files downloaded by pip download sampleproject
twine upload --repository-url https://${env.REGION}-pypi.pkg.dev/${env.PROJECT_ID}/${env.REPO_NAME} sampleproject-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl --verbose
```

Looks like I don't even need to set the .pypirc, or other python configuration files. This makes a lot of sense since this is a 100% ephemeral jenkins agent.

Finally the problem was to install `keyring` first (base on the official documentation), it seems that when working in a workload identity container it is not necessary.